# Error expression expected when concating query string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following query in vb.net which gives the error expression expected on the 2nd line
in my code the 2nd line is     & " from groups, Group_permissions " &  _ 
and it highlights the & with blue saying expected expression ?

```
           Using Grp As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(" select Groups.Group_ID, Count
                                       (Group_PErmissions.Access_ID) as Cnt " & _ 
                                        & " from Groups, Group_Permissions " & _ 
                                  & " where Groups.Group_Id = Group_Permissions.Group_ID " & _ 
                                            & " and Groups.Group_Name = " & "'" & 
                                            Cmb_Groups.Text & "'" & _ 
                                            & " group by Groups.Group_Id ", App_Connection  )
             End Using
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: & _ means concatenate but continue on another line.  The other & is redundant.  remove all the &'s at the beginning of the lines.

Comment: Another suggestion using string.join or string builder it will make code more readable at my personal suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Using Grp As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(" select Groups.Group_ID, Count (Group_PErmissions.Access_ID) as Cnt " & _ 
                                         " from Groups, Group_Permissions " & _ 
                                         " where Groups.Group_Id = Group_Permissions.Group_ID " & _ 
                                         " and Groups.Group_Name = " & "'" & Cmb_Groups.Text & "'" & _ 
                                         " group by Groups.Group_Id ", App_Connection  )
End Using
```

I have not tested this in VB for other syntactical errors.  But that should fix the error you were seeing.